# Is is true Superstring theory does not satisify diffeomorphism invariance?

Tags: string-theory, diffeomorphism-invariance

So it is well known that string theory contains General Relativity in the classical limit. And assuming the spin-2 fields all couple correctly to the other fields this means it is diffeomorphism invariant in the classical limit.

But is the quantized string theory actually diffeomorphism invariant in the 26 space-time dimensions?

I know loop-quantum gravity claims to be diffeomorphism invariant "all the way down". So is this different to string theory?

Comment: how is this different from [this previous question of yours](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/416244/84967)?

Comment: That one is specifically about String Field Theory for which is less developed. I made this question simpler and very much to the point. Hopefully someone will know the answer. I am reading this. http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/11116/1/Huggett-Vistarini.pdf Hopefully it will explain it.

Comment: Note that your question is about "Superstring", for which the critical dimension is 10, not 26.